# Labeling a bar chart, changing how rotated labels are centered

Tags: graphics, plotting

I'm trying to label a bar chart with rotated labels

see this simple example:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], BarSpacing -> Large, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[ToString /@ RandomReal[100000, 10], Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &]]
```

In this case the center of the label is aligned with the center of the bar.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want the right/top of the label to be aligned with the center of the bar instead, basically shift the labels over a bit to the left. How can this be done?

Also, what if all the labels have different lengths:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You could try including an `AdjustmentBox` in your `Placed` function. I haven't time to write this up as a full answer just now but someone else might like to try.

Comment: s0rce, you may wish to revisit this question.  belisarius's method no longer works in version 10, while Brett's does, and also for other plots as well.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default the `Axis` position that you're using centers the label under the bar along the axis. For long text that's rotated at a slant, it generally looks bad.  (It works fine for horizontal and vertical text, however.)

---

Here's one approach, using a different second argument for `Placed`:

```
Module[{
    labels = {"Learning focused", "Positively oriented", "Continuous", 
              "Timely", "Clear criteria", "Flexible", "Suited to student level"}, 
    data = {8, 6, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9}
    }, 
    BarChart[data, 
        ChartLabels -> Placed[
            labels, 
            {{0.5, 0}, {0.9, 1}}, 
            Rotate[#, (2/7) Pi] &
            ], 
        PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}}, Ticks -> {None, Range[0, 10, 2]}, 
        ImagePadding -> {{20, 0}, {95, 0}}
    ]
]
```

[image]

The first part of the argument, `{0.5, 0}`, says to place the label halfway across the bar, at the bottom.

The second part of the argument, `{0.9, 1}`, says what part of the label at the first part. In this case it's near, but not quite at, the right-top corner.

It's not exactly at the corner, because I think it looks better if the top of the "ink" is centered below the bars, and that won't be the actual corner unless your label ends with ">" or something similar.

---

Here's a second approach, using a different third argument of `Placed`:

```
Module[{
    labels = {"Learning focused", "Positively oriented", "Continuous", 
              "Timely", "Clear criteria", "Flexible", "Suited to student level"}, 
    data = {8, 6, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9}
    }, 
    BarChart[data, 
        ChartLabels -> Placed[
            labels, 
            Axis, 
            Block[{text = Rotate[#, (2/7) Pi]}, 
                Row[{text, Invisible[text]}, 
                    "\[NegativeMediumSpace]"]
            ]&
            ], 
        PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 10}}, Ticks -> {None, Range[0, 10, 2]}, 
        ImagePadding -> {{20, 0}, {95, 0}}
    ]
]
```

This uses the normal axes positioning, but for each label, it creates an object that has the label and an invisible copy of the label side-by-side so that the center of the object is the end of the visible label. (I used a negative space between the objects, because again I think it looks better.) The nice thing about this approach is that the basic idea can be used for labels for ticks on axes that don't otherwise allow specific placements.

[image]

Comment: Much more elegant than my version, +1! My function was built to be used with `FrameTicks`, not `Placed`, so I didn't have these options.

Comment: @Verbeia The second approach should also work with frame ticks.

Answer (score 12):

It can be done using the *pos* parameter of `Placed`:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], BarSpacing -> Large, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[(ToString /@ 10^RandomInteger[10, 10]), 
         {{1, 0}, {1, 1}} 
         (* pos: bar position: lower right corner (1,0), 
                 text box:     upper right corner (1,1)  *), 
         Rotate[#, Pi/4] &
  ]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use {0.5,0} instead of {1,0} to align with the bottom center of the bar (which I find slightly less esthetical pleasing, but YMMV):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: NIce approach. I find {0.75, 0} more pleasing to the eye than {0.5, 0}.

Comment: I also like {0.75,0} however, the labels are slightly closer to the Axis here then they are with Axis, can this be solved? edit: {{0.75, 0}, {1, 1.1}} looks a bit better but I think it makes the top uneven.

Answer (score 12):

Something like this could also do:

```
BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], BarSpacing -> Large, 
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[ToString /@ 
     RandomChoice[ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}, "Words"], 10], 
     Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/4] &]] /. 
 ImageScaled[{1/2, 1}] -> ImageScaled[{0.9, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice to see you at the site.  Btw, I wasn't able to get your code to run (even after changing `EampleData` to `ExampleData`.

Comment: @DavidCarraher: Please try now.

Comment: It works great!

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks for the edit!

Comment: I'm sorry to report that this no longer works in *Mathematica* 10.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard What? They did away with the Declaration of Independence?

Comment: I hope not!  Rather it seems that `ImageScaled` is no longer used in the output of `BarChart`.

Answer (score 11):

Here is a function I had lying around to deal with the same problem. Note you need to specify your font and size somewhere first, or your could adapt the following function to take options.

The issue is that `Rotate` rotates around the center of the item, not around some point corresponding to a top edge or corner. This code works out where the top corner should be, and adds margins to the box so that the top corner stays centred on the bar. Depending on where you actually want the labels to be, you might need to adapt this a little. This function was designed for the case where the labels were always at the bottom of a framed chart.

```
font = "Arial"; 
fsize = 12;     
rotatelabel[xlist : {(_String | _Style) ..}, rads_]/; Length[xlist]>2 := 
 With[{len = Length[xlist], cosdeg = Cos[rads]}, 
  DisplayForm@AdjustmentBox[
      Style[Rotate[#, rads, If[Sign[rads] == 1, {Left, Bottom}, {Right, Top}]], 
       FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> fsize], 
      BoxMargins -> {{If[rads < 0,  Max[0, cosdeg*(Plus @@ 
         ImageDimensions[Rasterize[Style[#, FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> fsize]]])/(fsize) 
         - 1.5 ((len-1)/len) * Abs@cosdeg], 0], 
         If[cosdeg == 0 || cosdeg == 1 || rads < 0, 0, 
          Max[0, cosdeg*(Plus @@ 
          ImageDimensions[Rasterize[Style[#, FontFamily -> font, FontSize -> fsize]]])/(fsize)     
         - 1.5 ((len-1)/len)* Abs@cosdeg]]}, {0.3, 0.25}}] & /@ xlist]
```

Example using your data:

```
BarChart[data,  TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12], 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[rotatelabel[labels, 45 Degree], Axis],   ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

The function handles the opposite slant, too, if that is what is desired.

```
BarChart[data, TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12], 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[rotatelabel[labels, -45 Degree], Axis], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Another example

```
 BarChart[data, TicksStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12], 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[rotatelabel[labels, -90 Degree], Axis], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

See if this works.

```
b = BarChart[RandomReal[1, 10], BarSpacing -> Large, 
 ChartLabels ->  Placed[ToString /@ RandomReal[100000, 10], Axis, 
     Rotate[#, Pi/4] &]];

b /. {Text[p_, Offset[ _, pos_], is_] -> Text[p, Offset[{-10, -2}, pos], is]}
```

[image: chart]

I used `AbsoluteOptions[b // InputForm]` to inspect the code and identify the `Text` commands that place the chart labels. I then offset the labels leftward by 10 printer's points.