# How to align rotated tick labels?

Tags: plotting, graphics

How can I align tick labels so the tick label text ends centered under the data point? Of Course it works fine with a rotation of 90 Degrees, but not with 45 or similar angles.

I see an example of how to do this charts but not with Plot or ListPlot
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2656/388

```
d = Table[n, {n, 10}];
xticks = Table[{n, 
Rotate["The y value is " <> ToString[n], 45 Degree]}, {n, d}];
ListPlot[d, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {xticks, None}}]
```

[image: Labeled list plot]

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4791/8

Comment: It actually is centered... Try for example with `xticks = Table[{n, 
    Rotate["The y value is " <> ToString[n], 45 Degree], {0, 
     0.2}}, {n, d}];` and you'll see that it intersects the text at its midpoint

Comment: @R.M "text *ends* centered"

Comment: Related: [(2652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2652/121)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Similar to [Szabolcs's and my answers here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4791/8), I would suggest writing your own custom tick function, so that the labels are set into a `Pane` which can be both `Rotate`d and have `ImageMargins`.

```
myTickList[min_, max_, seg_, shift_?NumericQ, phi_?NumericQ, len_: 0.01] := 
 Table[{i, Rotate[Pane[Style["y =" <> ToString[i], LineSpacing -> {0, 12}], 
     FrameMargins -> {{shift, 0}, {0, 0}}], phi], {len, 0}}, 
    {i, If[Head[seg] === List, Union[{min, max}, seg], 
    Range[min, max, seg]]}]
```

Examples:

```
fakedata = Accumulate@RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.5], 40];

ListLinePlot[fakedata, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,  Automatic}, {myTickList[0, 40, 4, 25, Pi/4], None}}]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[fakedata, Frame -> True, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {myTickList[0, 40, 4, 5, Pi/3], None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm seriously frustrated of how complicated this is ...

Answer (score 11):

Brett Champion posted a nice clean method in [Labeling a bar chart, changing how rotated labels are centered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2652/121) that can be applied here as well:

```
center = Row[{#, Invisible[#]}, "\[NegativeThickSpace]"] &;

d = Range[10];

xticks = Table[{n, center @ Rotate["The y value is " <> ToString[n], 45 Degree]}, {n, d}];

ListPlot[d, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {xticks, None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution, but the placement still looked a bit off.  This is easy to adjust by adding additional characters of \[NegativeThickSpace] to the Row command.  However, since Mathematica automatically subs out the name for a blank character that's difficult to edit, I found it easier to instead use `FromCharacterCode[Table[62340, {x}]]` and play with the value of `x` until it looks good.  `x=4` was the magic number for me.