# Style ticks individually

Tags: ticks

Is there any way to style individually ticks in `Plot3D`?  I want to draw `xmin`  ticks in a `Plot3D` graphics in red and `xmax` ticks in green.

Comment: Please provide a small code sample to work with. What is `xmin` and `xmax`?

Comment: This might be helpful https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27747/8070 . The answer was for direction but you can modify colour as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can add individual ticks with `Graphics3D`.

```
xmin = -2; xmax = 2;
major = Range[xmin, xmax, 1];
minor = Complement[Range[xmin, xmax, 1/5], major];
ticklen = 0.1;

Show[
 Plot3D[Exp[-(x^2 + y^2)], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Ticks -> major,
                                TicksStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold]],
 Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.01],
             Blue, Table[Line[{{x, -2, 0}, {x, -2, 0 + ticklen}}], {x, major}],
             Red, Table[Line[{{x, -2, 0}, {x, -2, 0 + 0.5 ticklen}}], {x, minor}]}], 
PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image]

I am feeling lazy now, so I leave the other sides for you.

Answer (score 0):

A custom `Ticks` function that modifies the default ticks ***to draw xmin ticks  in Red  and xmax ticks in Green:***

```
ClearAll[tickF];
tickF[mintstyle_ : Directive[CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.01], Red], 
   maxtstyle_ : Directive[CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.01], Green], tsize_: {.025, 0}] := 
 Module[{tt = SortBy[DeleteDuplicates[Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][##], 
   #[[1]] === #2[[1]] &], First]},
  tt[[1]] = Join[tt[[1]], {tsize, mintstyle}];
  tt[[-1]] = Join[tt[[-1]], {tsize, maxtstyle}]; tt] &
```

**Examples:**

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -10, 10}, Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 1},
  Ticks -> tickF[]]
```

[image]

Use `Ticks -> {tickF[] , Automatic, Automatic}` to apply it to the x-axis only:
[image]

```
Plot3D[(4 x^2 - y^2) , {x, -3, 3}, {y, -6, 6}, 
 PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5], Mesh -> None, BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 1}, 
 Ticks -> {tickFX[Directive[CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.01], Orange], 
     Directive[CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.01], Magenta], {0.03, .03}], 
   tickFX[], 
   tickFX[Directive[CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.01], Purple], 
     Directive[CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.01], Cyan], {0.05, 0}]}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[.1]}]
```

[image]