# How do I change the orientation of tick marks in a 3D plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, ticks

I'm putting together a series of plots for a paper I'm writing and they're not coming out quite right. Here is an example of one of them:

```
Plot3D[
   Sqrt[kx^2 + ky^2], {kx, -Pi, Pi}, {ky, -Pi, Pi}, 
   ImageSize -> 10*(72/2.54),
   ViewPoint -> {10, 10, 1}*100,
   ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 100}, 
   LabelStyle -> {Black, FontFamily -> "Times"},
   BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.75}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green, Opacity[0.9]]},
   Mesh -> None,
   AxesEdge -> {{+1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}},
   PlotPoints -> 100, 
   AxesLabel -> {Subscript[k, x], Subscript[k, y], Style["z", Italic]}
]
```

If you put this into Mathematica, you'll see that the tick marks of the "kx" look pretty good, but those of the "ky" axis are parallel to the horizontal plane which makes them hard to see. If they were vertical like "kx" it would look much better, but I'm not sure how to change that.

It seems like the program just chooses the orientation of the ticks automatically.

**Is there some command that allows me to choose the orientation by hand?**

[image: Plot with bad tick marks]

Comment: Downvotes without explanation and/or comments...(sighs) It is expected that you provide us with the code that reproduces the issues you are facing. Please, do not post screenshots and consider to add the code in a form that is easy to copy/paste for us so you can receive help. You can edit your post and use the palette that you see on top to format your question properly. Welcome to Mma.S.E.

Comment: Thanks for amending your post. Can you have a look at this [suggested solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27656/how-do-you-adjust-tick-direction-on-a-3d-plot)? Does this do what you need?