# How to place rotated text labels on a discrete plot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to create a discrete plot with horizontal tick labels consisting of specified text. Here's a simple example:

```
X={2,3,4,5}
DiscretePlot[X[[k]], {k, 1, 4}]
```

My labels are stored in a list:

```
labels={bob,ted,carol,alice}
```

I'd like to know what options added to the DiscretePlot command will yield a result in which the label names appear along the horizontal axis, with each name appearing under the corresponding segment in the plot. Because I'll eventually have names of longer length, I'd also like to rotate the name labels a specified amount, e.g. 45 degrees.

Comment: Related? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9530/how-to-align-rotated-tick-labels

Answer (score 4):

```
xx = {2, 3, 4, 5};
labels = {bob, ted, carol, alice};

DiscretePlot[xx[[k]], {k, 1, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, Automatic}}, ImagePadding -> 55, 
 Ticks->{Transpose[{Range@4, Column /@ Transpose[{Range@4, Rotate[#, Pi/2]& /@ labels}]}], 
   Automatic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** Alternatively, use `Epilog` or `Prolog`:

```
lp = ListPlot[List /@ Thread[{Range@Length@xx, -1/2}], 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[{Black, FontSize -> 14}], 
   PlotMarkers -> (Rotate[ToString@#, Pi/4] & /@ labels)];

DiscretePlot[xx[[k]], {k, 1, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, Automatic}}, Filling -> Axis, 
 ImagePadding -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {100, Automatic}}, 
 Epilog -> lp[[1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
X = {2, 3, 4, 5};
DiscretePlot[X[[k]], {k, 1, 4}, 
 Ticks -> {{{1, Rotate["Bob", 45]}, {2, Rotate["Ted", 45]}, {3, 
     Rotate["Carol", 45]}, {4, Rotate["Alice", 45]}}, Automatic}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Automatic}]
```

Notice the use of the `Ticks` option with the `Rotate` wrapper.

[image: Rotated ticks]

Edit: Or even something like this if you want to maintain the tick's number as well:

```
labels = {"bob", "ted", "carol", "alice"};
rotatedLabels = 
 MapThread[{#1, Column[{#1, Rotate[#2, Pi/2]}]} &, {Range[4], labels}]

X = {2, 3, 4, 5};
DiscretePlot[X[[k]], {k, 1, 4}, Ticks -> {rotatedLabels, Automatic}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: I think they wanted the numbers in the ticks, as well as labels below the numbers.

Comment: @Nasser I didn't gather that originally as it wasn't made explicitly clear, but I've edited my response to hopefully accommodate the OP in case that's what they're after. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. The MapThread suggestion works well, and I've been able to easily modify the idea for application barplots and matrix plots.