# Prevent scientific form plot ticks

Tags: plotting, ticks

How can I most cleanly force Mathematica not to print ticks in scientific notation? Do I have to manually provide the tick labels?

Rendering the numbers in exact form would be sufficient. If there is a way to express formatting with a function that would be optimal.

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 10^10}]
```

[image]

Comment: What would you like the tick labels to look like, then?

Comment: Good question -- let me add more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
longticks = 
  Show[#, AbsoluteOptions[#, 
      Ticks] /. {n_?NumberQ, n_, a_List, b_List} :> {n, AccountingForm[n], a, b}] &;

Plot[x, {x, 0, 10^10}] // longticks
```

[image]

Recommended reading:

- [How to align rotated tick labels?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9530/121)
- [About the number format in ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5369/121)

Comment: Does this still work with MM 13? I'm copy-pasting this code and get numbers in the format of 8*^9 etc.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Table` function or something similar within the `Ticks` option to make this easy on you. Consider this, which changes the y-axis ticks, while leaving the x-axis ticks alone:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 10^10}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[{2 i 10^9, 2 i 10^9}, {i, 1, 5}]}]
```

[image]