# Make rotated labels to be the near position of ticks?

Tags: ticks, alignment, textalignment

When rotate the tick labels, the labels will be centered at the tick position.

```mathematica
ListPlot[Table[ Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/180}], Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{{-1, -a}, {0, 0}, {1, a}}, {-1, 0, 
     1}}, {{{0, 0}, {180, Rotate[bbbb, 45 Degree]}, {360, 
      ccccc} }, {0, 180, 360 }}}]
```

[image]

How to align the right most of **bbbb** with the tick position? Such as:

[image]

Comment: closely related Q/A: [How to align rotated tick labels?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65390/125)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{180, Row[{Rotate[bbbb, 45 Degree], Spacer[20]}]}
```

and play with the argument of `Spacer`until you get the desired position.

Have fun!

Comment: I think he wants it to be automatic

Comment: @user5601 I do not think that such an automatic way exists.