# How to align rotated BarChart labels?

Tags: plotting

I'd like to use long text labels for a simple `BarChart`, but when I apply a rotation to label strings with different lengths the end of the text is no longer aligned with the bars in the chart:

```
Module[{
labels={"Learning focused","Positively oriented",
"Continuous","Timely","Clear criteria","Flexible",
"Suited to student level"},
data={8,6,4,5,5,9,9}},
BarChart[data,ChartLabels->Placed[labels,Axis,Rotate[#, (2/7) Pi]&],
PlotRange->{Automatic,{0,10}},
Ticks->{None,Range[0,10,2]},
ImagePadding->{{10,0},{95,0}}]]
```

[image: BarChart with misaligned labels]

If I try to incorporate `Translate` directly into the manipulation using `Rotate`, I end up with problems (Translate doesn't evaluate).

So, how can I re-write the positioning function

```
ChartLabels->Placed[labels,Axis,Rotate[#, (2/7) Pi]&
```

for the labels to both rotate and translate the chart labels? Is there an intelligent way to do this by using the individual dimensions of the labels?

Comment: Related: [(2652)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2652/121),
[(8378)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8378/121),
[(9530)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9530/121)