# How do I label the x-axis bars in my bar chart?

Tags: labeling, charts

input:     `BarChart[{{322065200000, 184408300000, 161032600000, 132462300000, 127267700000, 535043800000, 1135020100000}, ChartLabels -> {"Latin America and Caribbean (LAC)", "Europe and Central Asia (ECA)", "Middle East and North Africa (MENA)", "South Asia (SAR)", "Africa (AFR)", "East Asia and Pacific (EAP)", "Organization for Economic Cooperation and Development (OECD)"}}]`

output:
[image]

I want the names of the countries labelled below the bars.
I also don't want the numbers on the y-axis to show scientific notation.

Ideally I'd want my graph to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
labels = Style[#, 16] & /@  StringPadRight[#, StringLength@# + 3] & /@
   {"Latin America and Caribbean (LAC)", 
    "Europe and Central Asia (ECA)", 
    "Middle East and North Africa (MENA)", "South Asia (SAR)", 
    "Africa (AFR)", "East Asia and Pacific (EAP)", 
    "Organization for Economic Cooperation and Development (OECD)"};

BarChart[{322065200000, 184408300000, 161032600000, 132462300000, 
  127267700000, 535043800000, 1135020100000}, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, {{3/4, 0}, {1, 1}}, Rotate[#, Pi/3] &], 
 ImageSize -> Large,
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks["Linear"][#, #2, {6, 6}] /. 
    {x_Real, _Row, z___} :> {x, IntegerPart[x], z} &}]
```

[image]

Use `ChartLabels -> Placed[labels, None]` and add the option

```
LabelingFunction -> (Placed[#3[[2, 1]], {{3/4, 0}, {1, 1}}, Rotate[#, Pi/3] &]&)
```

to get the same picture.

Use `Row[{IntegerPart[x]/10^9, "B"}]` instead of  `IntegerPart[x]` to get:

[image]

Comment: See also: [this answer by Brett Champion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63276/125)